# inside colorbox, input{table.tex} fails with caption but succeeds without caption

Tags: tables

Please note that these `table.tex` and `caption_table.tex` are generated via `pandas.DataFrame.to_latex()` with actual command given in the comments of each table.

An acceptable solution would omit any manual editing of these tables.

### MWE 1. (no caption, working):

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
```

#### test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
% formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


% figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% date
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}

\begin{document}

\section*{section with table}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=black]
  \textit{min, max, mean, variance of all features.}
  \tcblower
  \input{table.tex}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

#### table.tex:

```
% command to generate
% pd.DataFrame(
%     {
%         "mean":np.mean(X,axis=0),\
%         "var":np.var(X,axis=0),\
%         "max":np.max(X,axis=0),\
%         "min":np.min(X,axis=0)
%     }).to_latex(buf="table.tex")

\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
{} &         mean &           var &        max &        min \\
\midrule
0  &   241.601104 &  8.349917e+01 &    253.000 &  193.50000 \\
1  &   227.376571 &  9.262559e+01 &    249.000 &  152.50000 \\
2  &   241.554150 &  3.528634e+01 &    252.500 &  214.25000 \\
3  &   232.826768 &  9.762573e+01 &    252.500 &  152.50000 \\
4  &  3089.923365 &  1.565151e+07 &  31048.000 &   10.00000 \\
5  &   928.259020 &  3.081762e+06 &  13630.000 &    0.00000 \\
6  &   138.093830 &  4.439517e+05 &   9238.000 &    0.00000 \\
7  &     3.248579 &  8.219485e+00 &    125.170 &    0.00000 \\
8  &     6.498653 &  6.405048e+00 &     19.167 &    0.87589 \\
9  &     2.097139 &  4.363440e+00 &     13.230 &    0.00000 \\
10 &     4.217660 &  4.086372e+00 &     66.761 &    0.00000 \\
11 &     2.691718 &  2.198778e+00 &     73.902 &    0.00000 \\
12 &    10.271590 &  4.046462e+02 &    975.040 &    0.99049 \\
13 &     5.781481 &  3.406521e+03 &    797.200 & -999.90000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

#### output:

[image]

### MWE 2. (with caption, compiler error):

```
$ pdflatex test_caption.tex
```

#### test_caption.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
% formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


% figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% date
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}

\begin{document}

\section*{section with table}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=black]
  \textit{min, max, mean, variance of all features.}
  \tcblower
  \input{caption_table.tex}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

#### caption_table.tex:

```
% command to generate
% pd.DataFrame(
%     {
%         "mean":np.mean(X,axis=0),\
%         "var":np.var(X,axis=0),\
%         "max":np.max(X,axis=0),\
%         "min":np.min(X,axis=0)
%     }).to_latex(buf="caption_table.tex",\
%                 caption="this is a caption")


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{this is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
{} &         mean &           var &        max &        min \\
\midrule
0  &   241.601104 &  8.349917e+01 &    253.000 &  193.50000 \\
1  &   227.376571 &  9.262559e+01 &    249.000 &  152.50000 \\
2  &   241.554150 &  3.528634e+01 &    252.500 &  214.25000 \\
3  &   232.826768 &  9.762573e+01 &    252.500 &  152.50000 \\
4  &  3089.923365 &  1.565151e+07 &  31048.000 &   10.00000 \\
5  &   928.259020 &  3.081762e+06 &  13630.000 &    0.00000 \\
6  &   138.093830 &  4.439517e+05 &   9238.000 &    0.00000 \\
7  &     3.248579 &  8.219485e+00 &    125.170 &    0.00000 \\
8  &     6.498653 &  6.405048e+00 &     19.167 &    0.87589 \\
9  &     2.097139 &  4.363440e+00 &     13.230 &    0.00000 \\
10 &     4.217660 &  4.086372e+00 &     66.761 &    0.00000 \\
11 &     2.691718 &  2.198778e+00 &     73.902 &    0.00000 \\
12 &    10.271590 &  4.046462e+02 &    975.040 &    0.99049 \\
13 &     5.781481 &  3.406521e+03 &    797.200 & -999.90000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

#### test_caption.log:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count339
\scratchdimen=\dimen296
\scratchbox=\box77
\nofMPsegments=\count340
\nofMParguments=\count341
\everyMPshowfont=\toks48
\MPscratchCnt=\count342
\MPscratchDim=\dimen297
\MPnumerator=\count343
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count344
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks49
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2019/12/03 v1.3 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 504.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
\c@lstlisting=\count345
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.


Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 21.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-english.def
File: fc-english.def 2016/01/12
)
(./caption_table.tex

! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \centering
              
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@xfloat ... \global \setbox \@currbox 
                                                  \color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.2 \centering
              
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vbox 
l.2 \centering
              
? 
) [1
```

Comment: why use `--shell-escape` here? (it's really not recommended to run shell-escape on arbitrary documents off the internet)

Comment: not in outer par mode means you have a table or figure environment nested insde som ebox

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle I will remove from the MWE.  

It was just copied from the original command I used to build my actual main.tex, where the compiler complains if --shell-escape is omitted (maybe because it has minted code?).

Comment: minted needs shell escape, it is probably also the source of the problem since the log you show is clearly using that and is not the log of the example posted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry I'm not familiar with the term, by ebox do you mean that:
mwe1 is:
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule

mwe2 is:
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{this is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, confirmed removing minted solves the issue, thanks!
Now the issue is how to import my tables without removing minted, I really need some way to include lines from my python files, as the document contains many of these code blocks.

Comment: no you get that error from eg `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}  \begin{table}...`  were `table` is inside a minipage.  the log you show is not from the code you posted but presumably relates to a document where some such environment is started but not closed before the table starts,

Comment: minted itself is not an issue, you have an error in the part of the document not shown. that is why you should always post the log _of the posted example_. the posted example has no error.

Comment: (in the hopes this does clear some confusions:) With "som ebox" @DavidCarlisle meant "some box", that was just a typo.

Comment: Thank you, I have confirmed this.  
I do not mean to inconvenience users like yourself who are trying to help.  
In the future I will try to be more careful redacting content to comply with project guidelines when composing MWE's that faithfully highlight the issue

Comment: I'm looking for the actual source of the error and when I find it I will update the MWE in the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "not in outer par mode" error means that you have used the `table` (or other floating environment such as `figure`) inside some box. The only purpose of a float is to mark its content as not in the main document flow, but an insert that can be repositioned and re-inserted to help with page breaking. This floating behaviour is structurally incompatible with being inside a box at a fixed point on a specific page.

The box here is from `\begin{tcolorbox}` you can not have any floats inside it.

Searching for `caption` in the tcolorbox manual suggests that you could use its `blend into` key to merge some `table` environment features. But simpler, do not use `table` at all, just `tabular` and then make the caption with

```
\captionof{table}{this is a caption}
```

where `\captionof` comes from the `caption` or (one-line) `capt-of` package.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough explanation.